# Windows : Replace character inside file

Tags: windows

Is there a command that would enable me to replace a character in a text file. 
Constraint : 
- File size is >= 100 MB

Comment: If techie007's comment didn't help you, we're going to need some more details. At the very least, what is your OS?

Comment: It is a special character (upward pointing arrow), and I use Windows.

Answer (score 1):

On **Windows**:

You could use a utility such as [grepWin](http://stefanstools.sourceforge.net/grepWin.html) to do a search and replace on the file.

Also, you can download an editor such as [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.5.5.html), and do a simple find and replace by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>

Comment: Notepad++ does not work fine. The file size is multi-GB, giving me problems opening them. Also the character is not a simple ASCII, it is an upward pointing arrow. The other team working on this uses ultraedit, and even that wont let me do a simple find-replace.